# Removing characters from a string passed from an HTML page

Tags: c#, html, trim

I'm trying to trim a string of some character so I can put it in an SQL query. An example of what is being passed to my method is "\n asdw_value\n". I want the "\n"s and the space to be removed, but I can't get the "\n" to go away. My code now looks like this :

```
element = element.Replace("\\", "");
element = element.Replace("n", "");
element = element.Replace(" ", "");
```

And the output has been "\nasdq_value\n" Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely the string value you're seeing is produced in the debugger. The `\n` is an [escape sequence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h21280bw.aspx) meaning 'newline'. It's a single character, not a `\` followed by a `n`, so to remove it from your input, you will need to use the same escape sequence, like this:

```
element = element.Replace("\n", "");
element = element.Replace(" ", "");
```

If you only want to trim these characters from the beginning and end of the string, you can do this:

```
element = element.Trim(new char[] { '\n', ' ' });
```